# Why is this template always evaluated to false_type?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I would like to `enable_if` a member function exists in a class `T`, so I try to write the code below.

```
    template< typename T, typename = void >
    struct has_member_func : std::false_type {};

    template< typename T >
    struct has_member_func< T, decltype(&T::some_func) > : std::true_type {};
```

However, it always evaluate to `std::false_type`, even if class `T` does have a function named `some_func`.
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use it like `has_member_func<X>`, the 2nd template parameter would use the default value `void`; but the partial specialization's 2nd template parameter's type is not `void`, then the specialization won't be selected; unless you specify the 2nd template argument explicitly to make them match like `has_member_func<X, decltype(&X::some_func)>` (which seems meaningless).

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fYWCpuciOSxwSQ6d)

In the partial specialization, the 2nd template parameter should yield the type `void` too, then the specialization could be selected. You can apply [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) (since C++17) like

```
template< typename T >
struct has_member_func< T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::some_func)> > : std::true_type {};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/I5agIqfPfAYbIKIO)

PS: Before C++17 you can make your own `void_t` easily.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't realize that default argument is applied first.